# Not select some tables in msqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a problem with working php interacting with a database, pretty much I want to show all the tables in the database except for one, because it is a system table, I tried it with the NOT operator but does not seem to work, you have any idea? I post below the code:

```
$sql_5 = "SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name NOT LIKE `sondaggio attivo`";
```

Comment: I think a `WHERE` would be useful

Comment: @RiggsFolly like this? SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name WHERE NOT LIKE `sondaggio attivo` not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the SQL needs to be syntactically correct.

Second the result row will have a column called `Tables_in_$db_name` so it is simpler to use `$res->fetch_array( MYSQLI_NUM)` to retrieve the result as the name would change for each database and this way you dont need to care about what database you are querying

So something like this for example should work

```
$db_name = 'test';
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name WHERE Tables_in_$db_name NOT LIKE 'sondaggio attivo';";

$res = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = $res->fetch_array( MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo $row[0] . '<br>';
}
```

As you are only trying to remove one specific table name from the result thsi would also work

```
$db_name = 'test';
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name WHERE Tables_in_$db_name != 'sondaggio attivo';";

$res = $db->query($sql);

while ($row = $res->fetch_array( MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    echo $row[0] . '<br>';
}
```